# X220 support for iAMT and vPro

Tags: laptop, amt, intel

While browsing through the [lenovo PSREF (tabook)](http://www.lenovo.com/psref/pdf/tabook_WE.pdf) for X220 model number 4287 (page 69) I noticed models that support iAMT and vPro and models that do not.

Can anyone shed some light on this. Some models have the same processor and I assume same motherboard but one supports vPro/iAMT and the other not.
Example:

```
4287-3KU iAMT/vPro
4287-2WU No/No
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself here: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/mobile-core-i7,2443-4.html

> The WiFi Link 1000 doesn’t support AMT 6.0, and therefore cannot be part of a vPro-enabled notebook.